# Angular - Sonar - Constructor has too many parameters (8). Maximum allowed is 7

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

[image]

My angular app showing above error message when it pass thought sonar scan. Is there any way to fixed it.

I want to pass 8 or 9 dependency but sonar lint not allowing. Is there any alternate way to make it possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use dynamic service injection in the component. In that case it will have one parameter and you can inject as many service as you want.

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myService : MyService;

  constructor(private injector : Injector){
      this.myService = injector.get<MyService>(MyService);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. It's working!

Comment: Mind that, this is just a hack that works but not a proper solution. Ideally you should design your component in a way that it should not have that many dependencies.